# Truncated tetrahedron

Tags: geometry

Consider a regular tetrahedron $KABC$ where its edges have length $x$. We take points $A_1$ on $KA$, such as $KA_1 = \frac12 KA$, point $B_1$ on $KB$ such as $KB_1 = \frac23 KB$ and point $C_1$ on $KC$ such as $KC_1 = \frac34 KC$.
Find the volume of tetrahedron $KA_1B_1C_1$ in relation to $x$.

I know that the volume of $KABC = \frac{x^3}{6\sqrt{2}}$.
Also the volume is $\frac13*$(area of a base)$*h$.
In the second tetrahedron the sides of the base can be calculated, since we know the angle of each triangle being $60$ degrees and the two sides (proportions of $x$). Then we can calculate the area by Heron's formula. But how do we calculate the height of the new tetrahedron? I calculated the 3 sides: $x\frac{\sqrt{7}}{4}$, $x\frac{\sqrt{13}}{6}$, $x\frac{\sqrt{73}}{12}$.

Also we know that the volume of the tetrahedron is one third of the cube that contains it.
Is there any trick? I suspect something with the circumscribed parallelepiped? Is there any such thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base $KC_1$ of triangle $KB_1C_1$ is ${3\over4}$ of $KC$, and its altitude $B_1N_1$ is ${2\over3}$ of the altitude $BN$ in triangle $KBC$ (by similar triangles). 
Thus the area of triangle $KB_1C_1$ is ${2\over3}\cdot{3\over4}={1\over2}$ of the area of $KBC$.

Height $A_1H_1$ from $A_1$ to the plane of face $KBC$ is ${1\over2}$ of height $AH$ from $A$ to $KBC$ (by similar triangles).

Hence the volume of $KA_1B_1C_1$ is ${1\over2}\cdot{1\over2}={1\over4}$ the volume of $KABC$.

[image]

Comment: you are a genius!